# Prevent AWS Autoscalingroup to start more instances than max size during update via Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, autoscaling

I have a autoscaling group defined via Cloudformation with this updated policy:

```
UpdatePolicy:
  AutoScalingRollingUpdate:
    WaitOnResourceSignals: false
```

The `maxSize` of the autoscaling group is set to 4. I have a lifecycle hook for starting and stopping instances.

When I uppdate the ASG (for example by changing the AMI in the LaunchConfiguration) it starts new instances before old instances are completely stopped (before the terminating lifecycle hook is finished).

Can I prevent this? Can I tell Cloudformation/The ASG not to start a new instance before the lifecycle hook is finished?

Answer (score 0):

**When I update the ASG (for example by changing the AMI in the LaunchConfiguration) it starts new instances before old instances are completely stopped (before the terminating lifecycle hook is finished).**

From the [Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling Lifecycle Hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html) and [Auto Scaling Lifecycle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/AutoScalingGroupLifecycle.html)
 :

Lifecycle hooks enable you to perform custom actions by pausing instances as an Auto Scaling group launches or terminates them.

Your newly launched instance completes its startup sequence and a lifecycle hook pauses the instance. While the instance is in a wait state, you can install or configure software on it, making sure that your instance is fully ready before it starts receiving traffic.

[image]

What you can try doing is, adding a lifecycle hook that pauses the instance while scaling out. In the meanwhile, your lifecycle hook for scale-in will finish its execution and later on pause on your scale-out instance will be released and it will be up. This will surely impact the creation of instances in normal scale-out conditions as your instance creation will be paused but you might utilize it for other activities like an upgrade, deployment, etc.

You can read about [Cooldowns and Custom Actions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html#lifecycle-hook-cooldowns) which might also help you.